# NodeJs: modify json object with non-strict jsonpath

Tags: json, node.js

In my work I need to test new api service. It is developing very fast, having huge request bodies.

In order to automate xml api testing, i found very comportable method when you set relative paths and changing values of found elements. It is simply done with xpath which allows such sort of methods.

But in case with json, i'm just stock. The main npm module called `jsonpath` just returning elements but not allowing to get some parameter and change its value like xpath does.

My problem in this case is that I want to write nice-looking tests, and if i will write them using absolute paths, they could be very ugly with long strings and there would be also much more of typing work in compairson with short relative paths.

So how this problem can be solved for this goal?

**List of npm modules to work with json path**

1. `json patch`: wants absolute paths and also having ugly way to change jsons as i understood.
2. `json path`: only returns separate values from search results.
3. `json-path-processor`: having `set` method, but also wants absolute paths.

**UPDATE**

I'm sorry, but the question is not about file paths, it is about changing values inside of json object using path to inner elements.

I want to set value 2 for `d` element in json

> `{ a: { b: {  c: [{ d: 1 }] }  } }`

using a path like `$..c[0].d` insteard of path `$.a.b.c[0].d`

Comment: `require('path').resolve('../..')`

Comment: @Plato thank you, Plato, could I change value in json object with it ?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan). It is powerful once you wrap your head around it. I'm sure you could solve your other use cases with it as well.

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const update = (needle, value, input) => objectScan([needle], {
  abort: true,
  rtn: 'bool',
  filterFn: ({ parent, property }) => {
    parent[property] = value;
  }
})(input);

const obj = { a: { b: { c: [{ d: 1 }] } } };

console.log(update('**.d', 2, obj)); // true iff replacement was made
// => true
console.log(obj);
// => { a: { b: { c: [ { d: 2 } ] } } }
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@13.7.1"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)